HTML form visible or hidden based on checkbox condition
I want to hide/visible a form based on checkbox in google webapp. If the checkbox is in checked condition then the form will be in visible else it should in hidden. I want to try with below mentioned code block. But not happen.


if (document.getElementById("df1").checked) {
   document.getElementById("co").style.visibility = "hidden";
} else {
   document.getElementById("co").style.visibility = "visible";
}
<form id="co" style="visibility : hidden">
<br>
<label type="text">Name </label><input type="text">
<br>
<label type="text">Roll No. </label><input type="number" value="0" min="0">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">

<input type="checkbox" id="df1">




PLease note that you can also do this using css only

This question is similar to: Show / hide a specific Div with checkboxes with HTML / CSS. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


Close the form.
Move the checkbox outside the form
Make a function and use addEventListener on the checkbox



window.addEventListener('load', () => { // when the elements are available
  document.getElementById('df1').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const show = e.target.checked;
    document.getElementById("co").style.visibility = show ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
  });
});
<form id="co" style="visibility : hidden">
  <label type="text">Name </label><input type="text">
  <br>
  <label type="text">Roll No. </label><input type="number" value="0" min="0">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<input type="checkbox" id="df1">



Using hidden (so the form does not take up space):


window.addEventListener('load', () => { // when the elements are available
  document.getElementById('df1').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    document.getElementById("co").hidden = !e.target.checked;
  });
});
<form id="co" hidden>
  <label type="text">Name </label><input type="text">
  <br>
  <label type="text">Roll No. </label><input type="number" value="0" min="0">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<input type="checkbox" id="df1">




The issue is because the state of your checkbox is only evaluated when the page first loads. You need to instead attach an event handler to the checkbox so that the DOM can be updated as the checkbox is interacted with.
Also note that the logic to toggle visibility can be made more simple by using a class.
Here's working example:


const cb = document.querySelector('#df1');
const form = document.querySelector('#co');

cb.addEventListener('change', e => {
  form.classList.toggle('hidden', !e.target.checked);
});
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
<form id="co" class="hidden">
  <br>
  <label type="text">Name </label><input type="text">
  <br>
  <label type="text">Roll No. </label><input type="number" value="0" min="0">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<input type="checkbox" id="df1">




or just form.hidden = !e.target.checked

You can use simple HTML and CSS for that.


input#df1:checked ~ form#co {
    visibility: visible;
}
form#co {
    visibility: hidden;
}
<input type="checkbox" id="df1" />
<label for="df1">Show Form</label>

<form id="co">
    <br />
    <label type="text">Name </label><input type="text" />
    <br />
    <label type="text">Roll No. </label
    ><input type="number" value="0" min="0" /> <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>



But if you still want to use JavaScript


const cb = document.getElementById("df1")
const form = document.getElementById("co")

cb.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) form.style.visibility = "visible"
    else form.style.visibility = "hidden"
})
<input type="checkbox" id="df1" />
<label for="df1">Show Form</label>

<form id="co" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <br />
    <label type="text">Name </label><input type="text" />
    <br />
    <label type="text">Roll No. </label
    ><input type="number" value="0" min="0" /> <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>




Why use if else on a boolean?

Is this correct?


function toggleFormVisibility() {
  const form = document.getElementById("co");
  form.style.display = document.getElementById("df1").checked ? "block" : "none";
}
<form id="co" style="display: none">
  <br>
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name">
  <br>
  <label for="rollNo">Roll No.</label>
  <input type="number" id="rollNo" value="0" min="0">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
 
</form>
 <input type="checkbox" id="df1" onclick="toggleFormVisibility()">




i mean you could put the trigger function where you need it

right,i just edit it

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
